# How to create multiple tables from large delimited file in SQL Server and setup for spatial queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a large vertical bar delimited file, that contains around 128,000 rows which contains multiple jobs codes designated by common number in column 1, I also have another file that contains 2 columns one with the job code number and the other that contains the description.

What I want to do is separate each job code into its own table, which will include name, address, zip code. After I have the tables populated I need to determine distances between different job codes and display the closest location of job b from job a.

Comment: What's the benefit of separating each job code into it's own table?  Are there multiple rows with the same code?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you take a close look at [SQL Server Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) (SSIS).

SSIS is designed for exatcly this kind of job - it allows you to load, parse, transform and ultimately store the data from any kind of sources into SQL Server.

You can run it as a one-time import, or you can store the package for later re-use for additional files you might need to import later on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using SQL 2008 which has Spatial Data support.

It sounds like you could have multiple jobs at the same site (i.e. address) so I would create a table of jobs that have a foreign key pointing to a sites table that contains columns for all of the address information and an additional column of type [Geography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895266.aspx).

You'll need to setup a process to populate that Geography typed column with Geocode info (i.e. Latitude and Longitude of an address), the [MapPoint Batch Geocoder](http://mappointbatchgeocode.codeplex.com/) is an SSIS process that uses the MapPoint(Now Bing Maps) Service and might be a good starting point for developing your own process.

Once you're able to get a Geocode for an address, updating your SQL table is easy.

```
UPDATE Sites
SET GeoLocation = GEOGRAPHY::POINT(@latitude, @longitude, 4326)
WHERE SiteID = @siteId
```

Regardless of where in your pipeline you integrate the Geocoder, I would recommend you abstract it in such a way that you can easily change the Geocode service provider or specify which one to use at run time because the services all have different pricing schemes and it might prove financially beneficial to use one over another.  For example Google offers 912,500 free requests annually at 2,500 max per day and no sessions limit, where as Bing only offers 500,000 requests annually with no per day limit but a limit of 125,000 sessions.  So for large batch requests Bing wins but for per item or random requests Google comes out on top.  In the end the quality of data from these services is comparable so there's no harm in changing your source to avoid fees.

Once you have your data imported and Geocodes populated it becomes trivial to calculate distances and find nearest neighbors.

```
DECLARE @Sites TABLE ( SiteId INT )

--Get the site ids you care about
INSERT INTO @Sites
SELECT SiteId FROM Jobs WHERE Status = 'Open'

/*
 *  For each site in your table variable @Sites, this will list 
 *  all the other sites in the variable in order of distance.
 */
SELECT p.SiteId
     , s.SiteId
     , p.GeoLocation.STDistance(s.SiteId) * 0.001 AS [Distance (Kilometers)] --https://www.google.com/search?q=meters+to+kilometers
     , p.GeoLocation.STDistance(s.SiteId) * 0.000621371192 AS [Distance (Miles)] --https://www.google.com/search?q=meters+to+miles
FROM Sites AS [p]
JOIN Sites AS [s]
    ON s.SiteId != p.SiteId
    AND s.SiteId IN (SELECT SiteId FROM @Sites)
WHERE p.SiteId IN (SELECT SiteId FROM @Sites)
ORDER BY p.SiteId, s.SiteId, p.GeoLocation.STDistance(s.GeoLocation)
```